# Recent versions TorBrowser removed Bing? What?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Google rejects Tor-based searches 100% of the time. Have used Bing. Why is it no longer one of the search engines listed? And BTW please don't ask me to install the Bing add-on because FFox says it's corrupt.

Update: "sej" suggested same "official" add-on. Tor prevents its download, see screenshot. Yes, I am running 6.0.2 
[image]

Comment: For better security, I switched to "**Duck Duck Go**"...... From what I understand, it DOES NOT have tracking related to it. It goes by the principal of ‘The
search engine that does not track you’.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there were problems with Bing using HTTP instead of HTTPS for certain types of results. (See [this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13860) ticket.)

Bing was removed in Tor Browser version [4.5a4](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-45a4-released).

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you having problems with visiting the website itself?
2. As far as i know, Bing isn't there in Firefox, hence TorBrowser also doesn't list it.
3. You will have to install the add-on to be able to search from the search bar itself. I believe this is [official add-on?](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bing/)
4. The site works fine, isnt blocking tor relays as I just checked.

Comment: The official add-on will likely exhibit the problems that caused support for it to be removed from the Tor Browser. Also note the other warnings associated with 3rd-party add-ons: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherExtensions

Comment: Thanks, that link was quite helpful. Probably bing can be restored if that add-on is fixed by now? (That ticket was around 17months old)

Comment: please see my updated post